# Problem with webservice execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I created a webmethod inside a Webservice to insert data into the database (SQL server 2005) and when I execute this webservice I get a error HTTP 500 Internal Server Error and the result is not displayed.

The code below is the webmethod to insert data.

```
public string insertData(string Username, string Password)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider MD5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            Byte[] hashDataBytes;
            UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
            hashDataBytes = MD5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(Password));
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertInToGrpUsrs",conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",Username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserKey",Password);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            return "Data Successfully Inserted";

        }
    }
```

A General question how can I chane the Password Textbox mode to "Password".

Can anyone please help me with these.

Thanks,

Comment: Just use normal TextBox for testing purposes?

Comment: Do you have a StackTrace available?

Answer (score 0):

This could be several things. Http 500 just means that something crashed on the server side.

You should place your code inside a try catch block and log the exception to find the cause of the http 500 error.